# Jetpack compose navigate forward

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I have a simple navigation flow:

Screen A -> Screen B

After I do some work in Screen A, I navigate to Screen B, and do some work there. Then I remember I forgot to finish a task in Screen A, and I press the system back button and it takes me back to A. I can see all the local states are preserved/remembered (texts in textfield, counts, etc). As I finish my task, I want to return to Screen B, but it is already popped off of the stack. So I manually navigate to Screen B, and with no surprises, the local states are gone.

My goal is, as I can navigate backwards easily, I want to navigate forward in same manner (states preserved). Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Navigation isn't really designed to work like that, but you can work around it by manually saving the states yourself. You can save specific data in `onSaveInstanceState()` and restore it in `onRestoreInstanceState()`, however there are some cases when `onRestoreInstanceState()` isn't called when the activity is destroyed.

You're probably better of manually saving your state in `SharedPreferences` in `onPause()`, and restore them in `onCreate()`